# SQL I don't understand what is wrong with my trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, database-trigger

I'm having a hard time understanding this error:

> Error at line 3: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "&" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ) , * & - + / at mod remainder rem  and or
>      as || multiset

1. CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER class_trigger
2. BEFORE INSERT ON Class FOR EACH ROW
3. BEGIN
4. IF (type = 'vl' && mass < 15000) THEN
5. mass := 15000;

**The code is:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER class_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON Class FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  IF (type = 'vl' && mass < 15000) THEN
  mass := 15000;
  END IF;

END;
```

What is wrong with my code? I'm using Oracle's APEX. Thanks.

Comment: replace  `&&` with `and`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. PL/SQL uses `AND` as the logical operator for the boolean AND operation, not `&&`.
2. When accessing fields which are passed to the trigger, you must qualify them with the `:OLD` or `:NEW` pseudo-row names.

Thus, you'd need to rewrite your trigger as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER class_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON Class
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.TYPE = 'vl' AND
     :NEW.mass < 15000
  THEN
    :NEW.MASS := 15000;
  END IF;
END class_trigger;
```

Comment: Bob, what happened to Monica!?

Comment: @Gary_W - [see this question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it)

Comment: Goodness, I didn't even know who Monica was before asking you.  I had no clue all this was going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @Gary_W - SO is the new Google.